# Activity starting through Async Thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have created

> AsyncTask

in Android Activity that continuously gettting commands from Server. How i can start another Activity when a specific command from Server is Received.
In AsyncTask i have written infinite loop, as it

> receives "HOMEPAGE" message from server

it should start HOMEPAGE Activity.

> StartActivity(new Intent(null, HOMEPAGE.class))

throws Null Pointer exception. what i should write instead of null as first argument.

Comment: StartActivity(new Intent(null, HOMEPAGE.class)). your 1st parameter should be a activity context like Activityname.this

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your activity context object as current activity if your AsyncTask was implemented in same class

```
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, HOMEPAGE.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

let your asyncTask hold a reference to your currently active activity:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

    public MyAsyncTask(Activity a) {
         this.a = a;
    }

    // your code
}
```

then you can start the activity with: `startActivity(new Intent(a, Homepage.class))` for example in the onProgressUpdate() method.

If you want to keep the AsyncTask running after that (to start another activty after some time for example), you have to update your activity variable after that via a callback method or something like that.